# Interpolate 2D arrays with different length in 3D space

Tags: python, algorithm, multidimensional-array, interpolation

I have a 3D cube of data of dimension 1024x1024x1024. I have traced and saved some path along different values of z-axis as shown in the image. These 2D arrays with constant Z have different length. I have only 7 of them and I would like to find a way to interpolate these data along z-axis in order to have one of these path for each 1024 z values. What interpolation algorithm do you suggest to use?

2D arrays traced in a 3D space

[image: [2D arrays traced in a 3D space]

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of information. It's unclear what you mean by "interpolation algorithm". I would suggest "linear" because it's very easy to implement. What is the datatype of these 2D "arrays"? From the graph, it also appears the 2D curves _do_ have a Z value — possibly 220, assuming Z is the unlabeled vertical axis.

Comment: These arrays are float arrays with x and y information. Each of them lies on a constant-z plane. They have been traced slicing the cube along the z-axis from value 400 up to 1024 with steps of 100. I would like to find the interpolated 2D arrays along all the rest of z-values.

Comment: By "array" do you mean a list-of-lists of float values  or an [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array) of type `'f'`? The fact that all the curves in slice of the cube appear to located in the same `220` plane seems to indicate they are composed of 3D values with that Z value. It might be best if you edited] your question and added some sample 2D curve data. Lastly, just saying you want to interpolate them isn't specific enough as there are multiple ways to interpolate between values.